# Требования STL к пользовательским контейнерам

Tags: c++, stl

Здравствуйте, пишу самодельный STL контейнер, и не могу найти список требований, которым он должен удовлетворять. Подскажите пожалуйста, где найти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раздел [Container requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements) в стандарте.